# Twitter API endpoint GET users/lookup not returning results it should return

Tags: twitter

I'm using the Twitter API endpoint [GET users/lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup) to retrieve fully-hydrated user objects for 20 users. All these users exists (they are politicians, old verified accounts, they are not suspended nor deleted). Still, the API does not return everything. I'm missing 8 users. The strange thing is that the endpoint [GET users/show](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show) works fine with these users. Has anyone encountered this issue and knows what's going on? Maybe there are hidden restrictions (for instance, if they've been massively followed over the last few day? Posting fake news?)?

Comment: What are the accounts? I’m curious to check whether the Twitter Developer Labs users endpoints return them. There should be no specific restriction on the users/lookup endpoint that I know of - if they are not protected, suspended or deleted they should be returned, I think.

Comment: @AndyPiper You can try with these 3: 1280415061367033858, 877836832406417408 & 800435764966215680

Comment: I just retried and it works now. Very strange.